# How to add a column to a data.frames when the data.frames are stored in one list

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of 53 data frames and i want to add a different column to each of this data frames, e.g. the first data frame contains 6 columns and 80 rows and i want to add a new column containing "Week1". The second data frame has 6 columns and 60 rows and I want to add a new column containing "Week2" and so on.

I have a vector containing Strings with "Week1" to "Week 53", but I don't know how to add this particular column to each data frame in the list.

So far I tried to write a loop and an approach with the lapply function, but I didn't solve it. I'd appreciate your help!
Below the codes of the two approaches I tried so far.
The loop:

```
for(i in 1:53){
  if(mylist[i]==name[i]){
    mylist[i] <- cbind(mylist[i],name[i])
  }
  i <- i+1
}
```

and the approach with the lapply:

```
f <- function(i){
  cbind(mylist,name)
}
myfilelist <- lapply(myfilelist,f)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try to use `Map` and `cbind` like so:

```
x <-data.frame(matrix(1:4,2))
myfilelist  <-list(x,x)

week <-paste0("week",1:2) #53 in your case

Map(cbind, myfilelist, week=as.list(week))

[[1]]
  X1 X2  week
1  1  3 Week1
2  2  4 Week1

[[2]]
  X1 X2  week
1  1  3 Week2
2  2  4 Week2
```

If you want to automatically create a vector of "Week1","Week2", use this:

```
week <-lapply(seq(1:length(myfilelist)),function(i) paste0("Week",i))
Map(cbind, myfilelist, week=week)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another idea (using the data of @PLapointe)

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

map2(myfilelist, 
     seq_along(myfilelist), 
     ~ mutate(.x, week = paste0("week", .y)))
```

Which gives:

```
#[[1]]
#  X1 X2  week
#1  1  3 week1
#2  2  4 week1
#
#[[2]]
#  X1 X2  week
#1  1  3 week2
#2  2  4 week2
```

---

As per mentioned by @alistaire, using the devel version of `purrr` (*v0.2.2.9000*) you could do:

```
imap(myfilelist, ~mutate(.x, week = paste0('week', .y)))
```

From the documentation:

> `imap_xxx(x, ...)`, an indexed map, is short hand for `map2(x, names(x),
>   ...)` if `x` has names, or `map2(x, seq_along(x), ...)` if it does not.
>   This is useful if you need to compute on both the value and the
>   position of an element

Comment: There's a shortcut for this in the devel version of purrr: `myfilelist %>% imap(~mutate(.x, week = paste0('week', .y)))`

Answer (score 1):

In case you are interested in `for loop` solution, here is one,I am assuming that number of dataframes and number of weeks are same :

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=2:11)
df2 <- data.frame(x=1:20,y=2:21,c=letters[1:20])
lis <- list(df1,df2)
vect <- c("week1","week2")

for(i in 1:length(lis)){
  week <-rep(vect[i],max(lengths(lis[[i]])))
  lis[[i]] <- cbind(lis[[i]],week)
}
```

**Output**:

```
> lis
[[1]]
    x  y  week
1   1  2 week1
2   2  3 week1
3   3  4 week1
4   4  5 week1
5   5  6 week1
6   6  7 week1
7   7  8 week1
8   8  9 week1
9   9 10 week1
10 10 11 week1

[[2]]
    x  y c  week
1   1  2 a week2
2   2  3 b week2
3   3  4 c week2
4   4  5 d week2
5   5  6 e week2
6   6  7 f week2
7   7  8 g week2
8   8  9 h week2
9   9 10 i week2
10 10 11 j week2
11 11 12 k week2
12 12 13 l week2
13 13 14 m week2
14 14 15 n week2
15 15 16 o week2
16 16 17 p week2
17 17 18 q week2
18 18 19 r week2
19 19 20 s week2
20 20 21 t week2

>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option (using the data of @PLapointe):

```
f <- function(i){
  myfilelist[[i]]$week <- paste0('Week_',i)
  myfilelist[[i]]
}

lapply(seq_along(myfilelist), f)
```

which gives:

```
[[1]]
  X1 X2   week
1  1  3 Week_1
2  2  4 Week_1

[[2]]
  X1 X2   week
1  1  3 Week_2
2  2  4 Week_2
```